# Invalid value '' for peerOwnerId. when create VPC Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have problem here when created VPC Peering in AWS. I want to create the architecture like this :

[image]

this is my first time to create VPC Peering. I have error says :

> Invalid value '' for peerOwnerId

What's wrong here ? I want to connect 2 VPCs in same Region, different AZ. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot seems fine. Maybe its console temporary glitch. Did you try re-trying the peering connection creation?

Comment: Yes. i have +24H try against to create VPC Peering but still same. I have checked the owner ID of the creation all resource to, the ID is same.

Comment: I have **change web browser** from Firefox to chromium and creation process is success. Maybe bug on web browser or because the extension in my firefox. And anyone can [check this solutions to](https://acloud.guru/forums/certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-Mggt36Qw8xTcKTKUqTF/lab:_build_solutions_across_vp) if have same problem.

Comment: Glad it worked out. You can answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have change web browser from Firefox to chromium and creation process is success. Maybe bug on web browser or because the extension in my firefox. And anyone can [check this solutions](https://acloud.guru/forums/certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-Mggt36Qw8xTcKTKUqTF/lab:_build_solutions_across_vp) to if have same problem.